# fill many input fields with the value from buttons with jquery and javascript

Tags: jquery

i have 4 inputs fields.
i try to field every input field  with the value from many button when i am on focus on this input field, but every time all input are also automatically filled.
how can i fix this problem please?
thanks

```
//input field
$("input.valu1").click(function () {
    $(this).focus();
    var $thise1 = $('input.valu1');

    $(".zahlen td button").click(function () {
        $thise1.val($thise1.val() + $.trim($(this).text()));


    });


});

$("input.valu2").click(function () {
    $(this).focus();

    var $thise2 = $('input.valu2');

    $(".zahlen td button").click(function () {

        $thise2.val($thise2.val() + $.trim($(this).text()));




    });
});


  $("input.valu3").click(function () {
    $(this).focus();

    var $thise3 = $('input.valu3');

    $(".zahlen td button").click(function () {

        $thise3.val($thise3.val() + $.trim($(this).text()));




    });
});
```

$("input.valu4").click(function () {
        $(this).focus();

```
    var $thise4 = $('input.valu4');

    $(".zahlen td button").click(function () {

        $thise4.val($thise4.val() + $.trim($(this).text()));




    });
});
```

[my code here](https://codepen.io/peanuts1984/pen/Mxmvzd?editors=1010)

Comment: Share your HTML code

Answer (score 1):

Your code is too complicated for its purpose.  More your code will grow, more it'll be difficult to add new component to your app. You need to *factorise* some part of your code.

Anyway, here is a way that you can resolve your issue. You may need to adapt it with your code.

```js
$(function () {
    var inputFocus = null;
    $('input').click(function(){
      inputFocus = $(this);
    });
    
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      if (inputFocus != null) {
        var valueButton = $(this).html();
        var valueInput = $(inputFocus).val();
        $(inputFocus).val(valueInput + valueButton);
        $('.error').html('');
      } else {
        $('.error').html("Error: you need to select an input first");
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p class="add">Addition</p>
            <table>

                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>+</td>
                    <td>93</td>
                    <td>=</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="valu" class="valu1"></td>
                    <!-- the last for the glyphicon -->
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>+</td>
                    <td>13</td>
                    <td>=</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="valu" class="valu2"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>+</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>=</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="valu" class="valu3"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>+</td>
                    <td>30</td>
                    <td>=</td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="valu" class="valu4"></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
  
    <table class="zahlen" style="margin:0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td><button>0</button></td>
            <td><button>1</button></td>
            <td><button>2</button></td>
            <td><button>3</button></td>
            <td><button>4</button></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button>5</button></td>
            <td><button>6</button></td>
            <td><button>7</button></td>
            <td><button>8</button></td>
            <td><button>9</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  <p class="error" style="color: red"></p>
</body>
```